# Use variable as field in ORM query

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to make an app that would resolve a URL into entries in the database. So I have a database with rows like ('name', 'date', 'value') and a number of entries like ('Tom', '27/12/2015', '5'). I wanted my app to resolve the URL the following way

```
http://.../app/name/Tom
http://.../app/value/5
```

In 1st case it should search for row named 'name' and then find an entry where this row equals a string 'Tom', etc. So this is the urls.py code:

```
    url(r'(?P<pole>[name|date|value])/(?P<nazwa>[\w ]+)/$', views.Pole)
```

and this is the views.py code:

```
def Pole(request, pole, nazwa):
    try:
        entry = Entry.objects.get(pole=nazwa)
        return HttpResponse(entry.wpis)
    except Entry.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse("Nuffin")
```

However it throws:

```
Exception Value:    
Cannot resolve keyword 'pole' into field. Choices are: name, id, date, value, wpis
```

I use Python 3.5 with Django 1.8.7 on Windows 7 x64

Comment: Entry model has a 'pole' field?

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean but I completely don't know how to resolve a value from a variable into a field. It's on different level of abstraction...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
def Pole(request, pole, nazwa):

    try:
        criteria = {pole: nazwa}
        entry = Entry.objects.get(**criteria)
        return HttpResponse(entry.wpis)
    except Entry.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse("Nuffin")
```

Comment: This is strange. I tried your answer but it threw another error so I checked what parameters are given to the views.Pole function and it seems that there is some kind of mistake in the URL regex because it 'cuts' the first variable to the last letter:

        return HttpResponse(pole + "" + nazwa)

returns only the last letter of 'pole' variable...

Comment: @KamilGorski Try adding '+' at the end, as in your second parameter

Comment: Thanks man! Now everything works! :) As simple as that! :) why did the regex catch only the last letter without the '+' ?

Comment: @KamilGorski You need specify the number of characters you expect, without '+' it will take only one.